# How to add and delete items on MATLAB Gui

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I'm a new MATLAB GUI user. I'm trying to add various number of items, let's say static texts on the GUI. The number and the position of items will be calculated according to input.

```
A = uicontrol('Style','pushbutton','Position',[0,0,50,50])
```

This code adds a pushbutton but I don't know how to use this button after creating that in this way. Does this A have its own handles or hObject? How can I make MATLAB display('someone pressed the button') when I clicked on the button?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to specify the `callback` property of the control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`A` is a `uicontrol` object. Its property `'callback'` defines what action is executed when the button is pressed. Specifically, the property can contain (see [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/callback-definition.html) for more detailed information and additional possibilities):

1. A char vector, which will be executed as code.
2. Sometimes the char vector this is just a call to a function that does the actual work.
3. A [handle](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/creating-a-function-handle.html) to a function, which will get called with two input arguments, specifying the object and the event.

So, in your case, you can do either of the following:

1. (Note that the quote whithin the char vector symbols are escaped by duplicating):

   ```
   set(A, 'callback', 'disp(''Someone pressed the button'')')
   ```
2. (Note that I am defining the as [anonymous](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html), and that it does not take any inputs):

   ```
   dispFun = @()disp('Someone pressed the button')
   set(A, 'callback', 'dispFun')
   ```

   With this approach, the function needs to be in scope when the button is pressed, so that it can be found by the interpreter.
3. (Note the function must take two inputs):

   ```
   dispFun = @(o,e)disp('Someone pressed the button')
   set(A, 'callback', dispFun)
   ```

   With this approach there are no scope restrictions. The function handle *defines* the anonymous function itself, which gets assigned to the callback.

   On the other hand, if the function resides in a file, say `dispFun_file.m`, using

   ```
   set(A, 'callback', @dispFun_file)
   ```

   again assigns a handle to the function, but that function is now on a different place. So if the function is modified (or removed from memory with `clear functions`) the callback will change.

Comment: When you do `set(axh,'xlim',lims)`, you assign the value of array `lims` to the property, not the variable itself. It's the same with `dispFun`. You assign the contents of the variable (the anonymous function), not the variable itself.

Comment: Or maybe `dispFun` contains the handle to an anonymous function, but that anonymous function keeps existing in memory for as long as there exists at least one reference to it. I don't know the internals...

Comment: @Cris Thanks to you for the suggestion!